# Why am I getting syntax error (JavaScript) trying to do a pagination?

Tags: javascript, jquery, pagination

Why am I getting a syntax error with this?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.post(some_url + "ajax/get_matching_products", {
        user_id : user_id_hash,
        url  : user_page_url
    }, function(data) {
        var callback = eval("(" + data + ")");
        //alert(callback.output);
        if(callback.result == 1) {
            $("#something").prepend(callback.output);
        }
    });


    /*
     * PAGINATION
     */
    $.fn.paginate = function(options) {
        var options = jQuery.extend({
             content: 'TBODY TR',
             limit: 20
        },options);

        return this.each(function() {

            var page = {};
            page.parent = $(this),
            page.content = (page.parent.is('TABLE')) ? page.parent.find(options.content) : page.parent.children(options.content),
            page.total = Math.ceil(page.content.size() / options.limit),
            page.display = page.content.css('display'),
            page.prev = 0,
            page.next = 2;

            page.content.slice(options.limit).css('display', 'none').addClass('ui-helper-hidden');

            $(document.createElement("DIV")).addClass("link-container")[(page.parent.is('TABLE')) ? 'insertAfter' : 'appendTo'](this);

            page.linkContainer = (page.parent.is('TABLE')) ? page.parent.next('.link-container:first') : page.parent.find('.link-container:first');

            $(document.createElement("A")).addClass("pagination-link previous ui-state-default").attr('href', 'previous').attr('title', 'Previous page').attr('rel', 'nofollow').text('<').appendTo(page.linkContainer);

            for(var num=0;  num < page.total;   num++){
                var offset = num + 1,
                      min = (offset * options.limit) - (options.limit),
                      max = (offset * options.limit);

                $(document.createElement("A")).addClass("pagination-link numeric ui-state-default").attr('href', offset).attr('title', 'Page '+offset+'').attr('rel', 'nofollow').text(offset).appendTo(page.linkContainer);

                page[offset] = page.content.slice(min, [max]);
            };

            $(document.createElement("A")).addClass("pagination-link next ui-state-default").attr('href', 'next').attr('title', 'Next page').attr('rel', 'nofollow').text('>').appendTo(page.linkContainer);

            page.wraps =  page.linkContainer.find('.paginationWrap');
            page.anchors = page.linkContainer.find('A');

            page.anchors.bind('mouseenter mouseleave', function(e){

                this.self = $(this);
                (e.type === 'mouseenter') ? this.self.addClass('ui-state-hover') : this.self.removeClass('ui-state-hover');
            }).eq(1).addClass('ui-state-active');

            page.anchors.bind('click', function(e){
                 e.preventDefault();

                 if($(this).is('.ui-state-active')){
                      return false;
                 }

                 this.siblings = $(this).siblings('.ui-state-active:first');

                 if($(this).is('.previous')) {

                      if(page.prev === 0){
                           return false;
                      };

                      this.link = $(this).siblings('A[href= ' + page.prev + ']');
                      this.link.add(this.siblings).toggleClass('ui-state-active');

                      page.content.css('display', 'none').addClass('ui-helper-hidden');
                      page[page.prev].css('display', page.display).removeClass('ui-helper-hidden');

                      page.prev--,
                      page.next--;

                  } else if($(this).is('.next')) {

                      if(page.next === (page.total + 1)){
                           return false;
                      };

                      this.link = $(this).siblings('A[href= ' + page.next + ']');
                      this.link.add(this.siblings).toggleClass('ui-state-active');

                      page.content.css('display', 'none').addClass('ui-helper-hidden');
                      page[page.next].css('display', page.display).removeClass('ui-helper-hidden');

                      page.prev++,
                      page.next++;

                 } else {

                      this.link = $(this);
                      this.link.add(this.siblings).toggleClass('ui-state-active');

                      this.offset = parseInt(this.link.attr('href'));

                      page.content.css('display', 'none').addClass('ui-helper-hidden');
                      page[this.offset].css('display', page.display).removeClass('ui-helper-hidden');

                      page.prev = this.offset - 1,
                      page.next = this.offset + 1;
                 }

            });
            return this;
        });
    };
});
```

---

Does this help finding the error?

JavaScript error in: 'clients/blabla/something/js/widget.js:
(275): html error: unable to find end of script tag

---

Firebug gives this error:

syntax error
$(function());\n

On it owns both parts works well if i put dummy/static content to tables, the pagination works aswell. but when those together it gives me this error :/

Comment: Please strip down the code to the relevant parts, no one is going to go through all this.

Comment: well the problem is that i dont know where the problem is, so how can i strip it down?

Comment: I've gave up on formatting the code, there is some unmatched brackets in first and second paragraph of codes, the rest havn't checked.

Comment: @adad1: Comment out inner parts of the code until there is no syntax error any more. That way, you can localize the error.

Comment: FireBug usually indicates the line of error.

Comment: By removing lines and checking if the error still occurs. If you boil it down to some (or in the best case, one) lines, you're much more likely to get any help.

Answer (score 2):

should have read more of the code context, the comma is valid where it is.

with

```
var callback = eval("(" + data + ")");
```

what is the value of data?

Comment: It's the next five lines as well. They all have the same error.

Comment: comma is a valid JavaScript statement separator and wouldn't throw a syntax error.  It would only throw an error if a certain keyword followed the comma, such as `return`, `continue`, `break`, etc.  Although, its usually only of use following block statements such as `if` or `for` without using opening/closing braces.

Comment: +1, I'd come to the same conclusion about the use of `eval()` but I noticed you'd already edited your answer :-)

Answer (score 1):

[Put the text in the jslint page](http://www.jslint.com) and you will get an answer.

Comment: JSLint doesn't show the error, most likely because it occurs inside the `eval()` statement.

Comment: on it owns that part works as well if i put dummy/static content to tables, the pagination works aswell. but when those together it gives me this error :/